# Unexpected error putting object on AWS S3 through browser (putObject)

Tags: javascript, express, amazon-s3

I get a presigned URL through my Node/Express backend successfully for a `putObject` request on S3 and try to upload the pertinent files through the browser.

When I make the the `put` request through the browser (or Postman) I get a `400` or `403`. I am new to S3 and not sure where I can look up information regarding this.

I know how to get the presigned URL correctly, but why is my `put` request for the files I got the URL for failing?

As far as I am aware the bucket I get the request for is publicly accessible.

I've looked up different code walk-through tutorials, documentation on S3, and posts here.

My code on the frontend to request presigned URLs

```
// Returns null or array of objects of type { url : string | null; contentType: string; }
const filesDescription = fileList[+key];

if (filesDescription === undefined || filesDescription === null) continue;

const Key          = `${prefix}/${filesDescription.name}`;
const ContentType  =  filesDescription.type;

const request  =  generateEndpointConfig(APIEndpoints.GET_PRESIGNED_URL, { Key, ContentType, userID });

const res      =  await apiCall(request.METHOD, request.URL, request.DATA);

const url = typeof res.data.signedUrl === "string" ? res.data.signedUrl : null;

presignedUrls.push({url, contentType:  ContentType});
```

The code on my Node/Express Backend to get URL

```
const { ContentType, Key } = req.body;

const s3 = new S3({
                accessKeyId: AWS_ACCESS_ID,
                secretAccessKey: AWS_SECRET
            });

const url = await s3.getSignedUrlPromise("putObject",
                {
                    Bucket: AMAZON_AWS_STATIC_BUCKET,
                    ContentType,
                    Key,
                    Expires: 300
                });

return res.status(StatusCodes.OK).json({ signedUrl: url })
```

And finally, the `put` requests I make to upload files

```
const presignedUrls = await getPresignedUrls(+idx);
if (presignedUrls === null) return false;

for (const fileIdx in presignedUrls)
{
  const fileList      =  files[idx];
  const uploadConfig  =  presignedUrls[fileIdx];

  if (fileList === null || uploadConfig.url === null) continue;

  const fileToUpload = fileList[fileIdx];

  try
  {
    // Make put request for corresponding file to cloud service
    await axios.put(uploadConfig.url, fileToUpload,
    {
        headers:
        {
            "Content-Type": uploadConfig.contentType
        }
    });
  }

  catch(err)
  {
    return false;
  }
```

I should also mention since I am doing this for authenticated users, I also transmit an `Authorization` header of the form `Bearer <TOKEN>`.

=== Edit ===

This is a sample error response I get back with status code 403 in **Postman**.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
    <Message>Access Denied</Message>
    <RequestId>...</RequestId>
    <HostId>...</HostId>
</Error>
```

=== Edit 2 ===

The policy on my bucket is

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "<POLICY_ID>",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "<STMT_ID>",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity <CLOUDFRONT_ORIGIN_ID>"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<S3_BUCKET_NAME>/*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "<STMT_ID>",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Federated": [
                    "http://localhost:3000",
                    "https://www.my-website.com/"
                ],
            "Action": "s3:PutObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<S3_BUCKET_NAME>/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

The CORS configuration on my bucket is

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "https://www.my-website.com",
            "http://localhost:3000"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```

For reference, this bucket feeds a CloudFront distribution for a CDN network and the bucket is restricted only as far as GET requests go on the domain level.

=== Edit 3 ===

This is the error I get back when trying to upload on the browser.

```
<Error>
<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
<Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message>
<AWSAccessKeyId>...</AWSAccessKeyId>
<StringToSign>GET [A_LONG_NUMBER] /[BUCKET_NAME]/[PREFIX]/[IMAGE_NAME].jpg</StringToSign>
<SignatureProvided>...</SignatureProvided>
<StringToSignBytes>[SOME_BYTES]</StringToSignBytes>
<RequestId>...</RequestId>
<HostId>...</HostId>
</Error>
```

=== Final Edit ===

Along with the answer by @jarmod, the issue was that my application config automatically forwards an `Authorization` header to all requests once users on the site are authenticated. Removing this header for calls to S3 made the process work successfully on the browser.

Comment: It's easy to find the list of [S3 error codes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/ErrorResponses.html#ErrorCodeList). The challenge is that a given error code covers numerous possible causes, so be sure to print out the full error response and include it above.

Comment: @jarmod Thank you for sharing the codes. That's really helpful to have. As you suggested, I have updated the post with a sample error response. Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that the AWS credentials supplied to your S3 service object actually have s3:PutObject permissions on the necessary S3 bucket/prefix? If they are OK, then read [Troubleshooting 403 Access Denied from S3](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-troubleshoot-403/)

Comment: @jarmod Yes, as far as I am aware, I have the correct policy in place for my bucket. This bucket feeds a CloudFront distribution for a CDN network which is restricted only as far as `GET` requests go on the domain level. For reference, I could not upload products on my website live or on my computer. I have updated the question with policy I have in place. I will take the time to go through the document you provided.

Comment: When you signed the putObject URL, you supplied the AWS credentials of an IAM user. That IAM user is the principal for the upload and that principal needs an IAM policy allowing s3:PutObject on the relevant resource. Your bucket policy does not allow this principal to upload. Related: I haven't seen an example of a federated principal being used in a bucket policy as you are using it. Are you sure this works? Typically it would indicate an identity provider such as Cognito, Google, or a SAML provider.

Comment: @jarmod Thank you for providing that clarification. That has almost solved the issue for me. I can now upload files from Postman. And I also looked into the bucket policy for the federated principal. And you are right, now the principal for that statement reads `"AWS": "<ARN_FOR_IAM_USER>"` I am just confused why I am getting a `SignatureDoesNot` match error on the browser. I noticed if I change the `Content-Type` header to an incorrect value on Postman I get that error. But I think I am providing the correct header on the browser too. If you put this as an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you originally signed the putObject URL, you supplied the AWS credentials of an IAM user (an access key and secret key). Later, when the S3 pre-signed URL is presented to S3, the original signer of that URL, i.e. your IAM user, will be the principal for the upload. Hence, either that IAM user principal needs an IAM policy allowing s3:PutObject on the relevant resource or your bucket policy needs to allow this to the IAM user principal.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a CORS configuration setup on your S3 bucket? This specifies which origins can access your bucket, and which HTTP methods they can use. In this case, you'll usually see an error in the developer console that looks like `Access to fetch at 'YOUR-PRESIGNED-URL' from origin 'YOUR-ORIGIN' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource`

This page goes over the basic configuration: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html

Comment: Hi Alex, thank you for replying. Yes, the CORS configuration is correctly set up as far as I am aware. I will update my question with the configuration now.

Comment: Nice, thanks. Yeah the config looks in order. If you open the developer console before attempting the upload, does that provide any useful error information richer than Access Denied?

Comment: None there. However, interestingly, the error message is different on the browser than on Postman. I will update my post with the error response.